# How to create plans without the "rails c" command ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I took a shared server to deploy my app, to begin. 
Everything works but I have some troubles to create my plans with stripe. 
On localhost, I can use 'rails c' to create them but my server don't allow me to do it.

Here's the command to create plans from the console :

```
CreatePlan.call(stripe_id: 'test_plan', name: 'Test Plan', amount: 500, interval: 'month', description: 'Test Plan', published: false)
```

The create plan method is a service object : app/services/create_plan.rb
Here's my create_plan.rb :

```
class CreatePlan
def self.call(options={})
plan = Plan.new(options)

if !plan.valid?
  return plan
end

begin
  Stripe::Plan.create(
    id: options[:stripe_id],
    amount: options[:amount],
    currency: 'usd',
    interval: options[:interval],
    name: options[:name],
  )
rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
  plan.errors[:base] << e.message
  return plan
end

plan.save

return plan
end
end
```

How could I create my plans with no console ? 
I tried with seeds.rb but it don't work.

Comment: You could create an "internal" controller and invoke this service object in an action. But I'd probably look for better hosting options. Supporting ruby/rails, but not allowing rails console, really?

Comment: You could point your local environment to production database (temporarily!) and execute this in your local console

Comment: what is the error you get when starting console ?

Comment: You're going to need the console, sooner or later.

Comment: @Nithin, the error : "rails command not found"

Comment: @Sergio, I agree, unfortunately I'm not a web developer and I can't waste time to learn how to use and program a true server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do stuff like this, make a [rake task](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks).

Like this:

```
namespace :stripe do
  desc "Create stripe plans"
  task :create_plans => :environment do
    # Do the business
  end
end
```

And then run `rake stripe:create_plans` on your server.

Comment: Thanks, I think I found another solution but I'll remember about rask task